# haml to html translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Can someone rails-haml expert translate please , how this haml code is translated to html ?
the page is derived from this [url](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/) . I m only interested in lines 1 and 12. I ve used the various tools , on line con verters but the dont seem to work :(

```
%table.table.table-bordered.table-striped#sortable{:data => {update_url:
sort_admin_things_path}}
  %thead
%tr
  %th= Title
  %th= Description
  %th &nbsp;
  %tbody
    - @things.each do |thing|
  # make the <tr>'s draggable by adding the expected '.item' class
  # pass the item id into params[:id]
  %tr{data: {item_id: "#{thing.id}"}, class: 'item'}
    %td= thing.title
    %td= thing.description.truncate(20)
    %td
      = link_to 'show', admin_thing_path(thing), :class => 'btn'
      = link_to 'edit', edit_admin_thing_path(thing), :class => 'btn btn-primary'
      = link_to 'destroy', admin_thing_path(thing), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?", :class => 'btn btn-danger'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not correctly indented. The big deal with haml is that things must be correctly indented to work. Otherwise you'll have unexpected errors due to the indentation.

Anyway..Try this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="sortable" data-update_url = <%= sort_admin_things_path%> >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <%= Title %>
      </th>
      <th>
        <%= Description %>
      </th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @things.each do |thing| %>
      <tr data-item_id= <%= thing.id %> class= "item" >
        <td>
          <%= thing.title %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= thing.description.truncate(20) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to 'show', admin_thing_path(thing), :class => 'btn' %>
          <%= link_to 'edit', edit_admin_thing_path(thing), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
          <%= link_to 'destroy', admin_thing_path(thing), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?", :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```